# What are the different types of makefiles and What is the difference between .mf and GNUMakefile files.?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, threadx

I have seen different types of makefile like GNUMake files in linux and .mf files in other code bases. Is there any difference between different type of makefiles.

Comment: Yours is a fair question, and user3159253 gave a good answer.  BOTTOM LINE: "Make" was invented a long time ago (in the 1970's), and lots of people have extened/changed the "basic format" for many good (and equally many not-so-good) reasons.  Hence variants like [Gnu Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), Microsoft [NMake](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha.aspx), etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Various kinds of `make` support a common set of Makefile structure elements, but all advanced features, like condition instructions, are implemented differently. See [this intro](https://wiki.netbsd.org/bsd_make/) on BSDMake, [an example of conditional](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html#Conditional-Example) in GNU Make (check adjacent nodes as well), and ≈[corresponding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbceedc7.aspx) part of Microsoft NMake reference.